# Where do I put iron-router code?

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

Where am I supposed to put

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route(name:String, options:Object);
});
```

and all other iron-router code with meteor? In the main.html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [unofficial-meteor-faq](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) for some file organization ideas. It should be under the `client` directory - e.g. `client/lib/routes.js`, but there isn't a strict rule about where it should go.

Comment: Hi David, is it not actually advised to put that in a folder that is also available to the server so that routes can be shared and server only routes can be defined within the same file?

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I prefer to keep my server code on the server, so I also have a `server/routes.js`. In our case, the server routes are pretty simple so there is no need for code sharing between the two.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on your answer? I would like to know if there are downsides to placing the routing code on the client. It seems... less secure... not that I know anything about that.